# cloning project from Git in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2, after migrating from Eclipse I pushed the project to a new repository. Now when I try to clone it ,it doesn't work.

After cloning it asks me :

Would you like to create a Studio project for the sources you have checked out to ?

I hit 'yes' and then "Import project from external model". 
I can see then the project but I can't run it. I can't even sync with gradle files. This option is not existent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation to migrate an Eclipse project to an Android Studio: [Migrating from Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). You should follow the step if you want your project to be usable under Android Studio since the project structure is a bit different betwwen the two environment.

Comment: The migration is already behind me. I ran it multiple times already on Android Studio. 
The issue is git related.

Comment: Mmmmh weird... Did you check the gradle files ? Did Android Studio created them ?

Comment: well yeah it seems ok. All the build.gradle files are in order, and all the rest as well.. 
I have no idea why it acts like this

Comment: Try to close project then close Android Studio. Then open Android Studio et click open existing project (do not click on your project on the left panel, use the open command so it will force Android Studio to reopen and rebuild the project from scratch and not from cache).

Comment: Ok can you show your project structure ? Also, check that that gradle files are not empty (espcially settings.graddle)

Comment: they weren't empty.. anyway, I created a new repository now , the issue in my opinion was that the project was inside another folder, so nesting folders caused a confusion (Studio related to it as just files instead of gradle build).
I might be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

You have to mantein this structure, with .idea and app directories directly in the root folder of your project, without any other wrapping folder.

[image]